# get the check box as checked based on the textfield which is coming from the database, in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I know you may get confused while reading the Title, I will explain my requirement below. That will hep you to understand the things more.

I have a loaded data grid , In that datagrid first column is checkbox, and and second column is "Name".  Also I have saved one field "Name" in the database . Here I want to make the checkbox to be checked if the Name is equal to the data which I stored in the database.

my sample code is

```
   foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdProduct.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Label lblproduct = (Label)row.FindControl("lblProduct");
                CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelectAll");

                for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dt.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
                {
                    DataRow r = dt.Rows[rowIndex];

                    if (Convert.ToString(r["productName"]) == lblproduct.Text)
                    {
                        ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelectAll")).Checked = true;
                       //chkSelect.Checked = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chkSelect.Checked = false;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Please look in this  code and let me know where I am going wrong... thanks

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: expected functionality is not working... am not getting the checkbox as checked with respect to the value.

Comment: I recommend you to debug and singlestep through it

Comment: Where do you have this code? After calling DataBind()?

Comment: yes , Mr. Kiran Hegde ,Gridvew have the values.